ionic v3 ios 17.5 windows.open not opening the URL
I have recently updated from xcode 12 to xcode 15.4 so that I will be able to meet the app store's requirement of building apps with IOS SDK 16.1
However, upon doing so I am no longer able to install the cordova plugin cordova-plugin-inappbrowser due to incompatbility issues Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-ios version. cordova-ios: 5.1.1, failed version requirement: >=6.0.0
Hence, I have replaced my iab code to open url's in another tab to using window.open however the link is not being opened.
How can I resolve this issue?
html file
<ion-row class="termsAndConditions">
      <div tappable (click)="openMobileBrowser('https://www.google.com')">{{'APP.terms_and_conditions' | translate}}</div>
    </ion-row>

ts file
 openMobileBrowser(url){
    console.log("OPEN!!!");
    console.log(url);
    window.open(url, '_system');
    // const browser = this.iab.create(url, '_blank');
  }


any logs in xcode?
